# Manipulating and tagging the duplicate entries in R dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
   id Name  Desc 
    1 A     abc
    1 A     abc  
    1 B     def  
    2 C     ghi  
    2 D     jkl  
    3 E     mno  
    4 F     pqr
```

I want to identify the duplicate ids and then mark the with duplicate as follows:

```
id Name  Desc Person
 1 A     abc  Same Person
 1 A     abc  Same Person
 1 B     def  Different Person
 2 C     ghi  Different Person
 2 D     jkl  Different Person
 3 E     mno  Different Person
 4 F     pqr  Different Person
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a logical vector with `duplicated`, convert it to numeric index and change the values based on feeding an input vector

```
df1$Person <- c("Different Person", "Same Person")[(duplicated(df1)|duplicated(df1, 
          fromLast = TRUE)) + 1]
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by_all %>%
  mutate(Person = case_when(n() >1 ~ "Same Person", TRUE ~ "Different Person"))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L), Name = c("A", 
"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), Desc = c("abc", "abc", "def", 
"ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqr")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -7L))
```

Comment: Nice answer!  Great thought process on base `R` solution.

Comment: Thank you akrun the dplyr library is an amazing one saved me many times.